# ¿Como obtengo la ruta completa de un archivo seleccionado con un campo type="file"?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un campo de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload">
```

Y quiero saber ¿Cual es la ruta completa?, pero al hacer `this.val()` desde `javascript`, me aparece lo siguiente:

> C:\fakepath\prueba.txt

¿Como se puede solucionar?

Es para obtener el archivo y subirlo a una conexión FTP desde laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cito la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176377/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-file-from-a-file-input) de stack over flow en ingles :

> No puede hacerlo - el navegador no lo permitirá debido a problemas de seguridad. Aunque hay soluciones, el hecho es que usted no debe contar con este trabajo.

Comment: Para subir un archivo a un servidor `ftp` ¿Como indico el archivo el cual voy a subir?

Comment: Te recomiendo crear una funcion php que se encargue de subir el archivo al ftp. Desde el javacript has un llamado ajax a esa funcion y envias el archivo! @PabloContreras